# Parsing through a file that uses whitespace as a delimiter -java. (I dont understsand it)

Tags: java, oop, parsing, arraylist, delimiter

Could someone help me understand what I am doing wrong please? 
I have to read through a file with 11 integers and doubles on each line, each line needs to become its own object and stored in an arrayList. However, the delimiter is a single space. And I have used this code, but it doesnt seem to work and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
package p2_0000000;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class P2_000000 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Which file year would you like to analyze:\n"
                + "1) 2007\n"
                + "2) 2011\n"
                + "3) 2013\n"
                + "(Enter number for choice)");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = input.nextInt();
        ArrayList<dwellingClass> alist = new ArrayList<dwellingClass>();
        if (choice == 1) {
            try {
                File file = new File("2007.txt");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);


                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = scanner.nextLine();
                    String[] info = line.split(" ");

                    int age = Integer.parseInt(info[0]);
                    int region = Integer.parseInt(info[1]);
                    double lmed = Double.parseDouble(info[2]);
                    double fmr = Double.parseDouble(info[3]);
                    double extremelyLowIncome = Double.parseDouble(info[4]);
                    double veryLowIncome = Double.parseDouble(info[5]);
                    double lowIncome = Double.parseDouble(info[6]);
                    int bedrooms = Integer.parseInt(info[7]);
                    double value = Double.parseDouble(info[8]);
                    int rooms = Integer.parseInt(info[9]);
                    double utility = Double.parseDouble(info[10]);

                    dwellingClass dwelling = new dwellingClass(age, region, lmed, fmr, extremelyLowIncome, veryLowIncome, lowIncome, bedrooms, value, rooms, utility);
                    alist.add(dwelling);

                }
                scanner.close();

            } catch (Exception a) {
                a.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
            };
            for (dwellingClass each : alist) {
                System.out.println(each);
            }

        }

        System.out.println(alist.get(0).getAge());
    }
}
```

I get these errors:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at        java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
```

Thank you everyone for the help!
I also figured out that this could also work for anyone who reads this post later:

```
public class P2_0000000 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        ArrayList<dwellingClass> alist = new ArrayList<dwellingClass>();
        try {
            File file = new File("2007.txt");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

            while (input.hasNext()) {

                int age = input.nextInt();
                int region = input.nextInt();
                double lmed = input.nextDouble();
                double fmr = input.nextDouble(); 
                double extremelyLowIncome = input.nextDouble();
                double veryLowIncome = input.nextDouble();
                double lowIncome = input.nextDouble();
                int bedrooms = input.nextInt();
                double value = input.nextDouble();
                int rooms = input.nextInt(); 
                double utility = input.nextDouble(); 

                dwellingClass dwelling = new dwellingClass(age, region,  lmed, fmr, extremelyLowIncome, veryLowIncome, lowIncome, bedrooms, value, rooms, utility);
                alist.add(dwelling);

            }
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception a) {
            a.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        };
        for (dwellingClass each : alist) {
            System.out.println(each.getAge() + each.getRegion());
        }
        System.out.println(alist.get(0).getAge()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: also, I couldnt get the last line(getAge) to print out.

Comment: `NumberFormatException` is returned when `parseInt` cannot parse a string value into an integer.  So you need to look at your data to make sure that you are reading the integers and the doubles in the right order.  To debug the problem, you could print out each value in the `String` array `info` to make sure that it is what you expect.

Comment: Can you include the file with the input which gives you the error?

Comment: I ran your code on this input file and it did not get any exceptions:
The first line of the input file: `1 2 1.1 2.2 3.3 4.4 5.5 1 7.7 8 9.9`
The second line of the input file: `11 12 11.1 12.2 13.3 14.4 15.5 11 17.7 18 19.9`

Comment: Thank you guys for the help! If any one is up for it, I posted the solution i came up with, but I still dont understand why my original code returned those errors.

Comment: @DavidChowller Thank you for the information and the help. I was wondering if you could explain this to me: I did not get those errors when during the middle of the while loop of the original code, I added a println statement. My theory is that it slowed the process down but thats just a noob guess.

Answer (score 1):

First you can read the file this way:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("2007.txt"));
```

Secondly to parse white spaces you will need to use something like this:

```
yourString.split("\\s+");
```

So your this line should become:

```
String[] info = line.split("\\s+");
```

Then you can access your `String` the way you did it.

But make sure that you are passing the right values i.e. the right types to each of the methods otherwise yo will get the error you are getting.

Comment: The question says that the delimiter is a single space, whereas your pattern will match multiple spaces.

Comment: You can also read the file with `new Scanner(new File("2007.txt"))`, which is what the question code is doing, so what was the point of that? --- Question says *"the delimiter is a **single space**"*, not white-space, so changing `line.split(" ")` to `split("\\s+")` will make no difference. --- So, it appears that only the last sentence of your answer is actually saying anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a number validation of the string you read from the file and make sure that it matches the requirements for building your dwellingClass object.

```
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String[] info = line.split("\\s+");
boolean validInput = true;
//loop through your info array and check each number is valid beforehand
for(int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
{
    if(!info[i].matches("\\d"))
    {
        validInput = false;
        break;
    }
}

//now we want to make sure our input was valid or else we don't create the object
if(info.length == 11 && validInput == true)
{
    dwellingClass dwelling = new dwellingClass(
        Integer.parseInt(info[0]), 
        Integer.parseInt(info[1]),
        Double.parseDouble(info[2]), 
        Double.parseDouble(info[3]), 
        Double.parseDouble(info[4]), 
        Double.parseDouble(info[5]), 
        Double.parseDouble(info[6]), 
        Integer.parseInt(info[7]), 
        Double.parseDouble(info[8]), 
        Integer.parseInt(info[9]), 
        Double.parseDouble(info[4]));
    alist.add(dwelling);
}
```

If you put this inside your while loop it will only create objects with lines read from the file that contain only numbers and contains 11 digits, other lines will simply be ignored. This would allow execution of the file even if a line is not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a NEW file, not loading your file. To load a file, you need to use a file input stream. your Scanner wont find anything in a new file and thus its all Null

---

I stand corrected, the syntax is correct and this would load an existing file. As others have mentioned above its a data issue

Comment: according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html, this is a valid use of scanner:
`Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myNumbers"));`

Comment: Very very counter intuitive, but okay I guess

Comment: Like Pritam says, this could be failing for white spaces, probably thats the reason, check your file in a regular editor by searching for a tab followed by white space or a white space followed by a tab

Comment: Why do you believe a new file is created? The [`Scanner(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-) constructor throws `FileNotFoundException` if file already exists, so it'll *never* create a new file.

Comment: Yes I stand corrected, I checked the documentation and found the syntax extremely counter intuitive, I suppose its because its not something I do on a regular basis in web apps. Never needed to load from local, most of the time not even allowed. But usually when initializing an an object with new, its a new object and ANY thing external from the JVM gets loaded from JPA or some form of InputStream so that new File("myfile.txt") seemed off